# Spring loading a UITabbarItem to navigate in iOS 11

Tags: ios, drag-and-drop, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbaritem, ios11

In iOS 11, UITabbarItem conforms to `UISpringLoadedInteractionSupporting` which defines the `isSpringLoaded` var.  In WWDC 2017 session 203, they indicate all you need to do to enable spring loading is set isSpringLoaded to true on a control, and dragging an item to it will trigger the action.

This works fine for UIButton.  But I can't get anything to happen with UITabbar.  I have a completely canned TabBarController in my storyboard.  I set

```
tabBarItem.isSpringLoaded = true
```

...for the viewController I want to spring load.  Dragging the item over that item does nothing.

I can't find anything in the docs to indicate what else should be done.

Comment: I think spring loading is still a bit buggy right now.
I have the same issue with collection View

Comment: Can you please explain here what is the purpose of by spring loaded for an UIBarButtonItem in storyboard?

Answer (score 0):

I've been working on this today and finally found the solution.

For some reason enabling the `isSpringLoaded` property from the storyboard doesn't work so what I done was I enabled the `isSpringLoaded` property from code.

A quick solution to enable all UITabBarItems to have springLoading is

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    tabBarController?.tabBar.items?.forEach({ (item) in
        item.isSpringLoaded = true
    })
}
```

This works on Xcode 9.0 beta 4 (9M189t)

Comment: I actually tried this exact thing earlier, because I observed that same thing (works in code, not storyboard) for a UIButton.  But this didn't work for me there, and even taking your code exactly it still doesn't work.  Maybe the prob is that I'm dragging a TableViewCell in this case?  Hadn't thought about it, but maybe that's not possible (tho TV -> TV certainly is)